# Kubernetes deployment works but can't connect to postgresql from pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a deployment and service yaml file. I use `minikube` to run `Kubernetes` in my `WSL`.

- postgres-deployment.yaml:

```
# PostgreSQL StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgresql-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: postgresql-db-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgresql-db
        image: postgres:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgresql-db-disk
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: testpassword
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /data/pgdata
# Volume Claim
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: postgresql-db-disk
    spec:
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 25Gi
```

- postgres-service.yaml:

```
# PostgreSQL StatefulSet Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-db-lb
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgresql-db
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
```

I run them with:

> # kubectl apply -f postgres-deployment.yaml 
> # kubectl apply -f postgres-service.yaml

The deployment works, I get the Cluster IP of the service with `kubectl get all`.

I run the pgAdmin with the command:

> docker run -p 80:80 
> -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com' 
> -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret' 
> -d dpage/pgadmin4

I try to connect to the postgres but I am unable to connect.
[image]

## EDIT:

- I changed the user for connection to `postgres`, still doesn't works.
- I tried to change the LoadBalancer to ClusterIp and NodePort, it doesn't work either.
- I tried to change my OS to Ubuntu, in case of some weird WSL issues, it doesn't work either.

Comment: it's strange, I have the same problem. when I connect via jdbc connection string and postrgres-driver or from an intelliJ database-plugin it works. but for pgAdmin as well as adminer it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

To access the Postgres locally, I have to use NodePort.
We need to find the NodePort ip and port.

- To find the nodeport internal-ip, do:

> $ kubectl get nodes -o wide

- For the port we can do `kubectl describe svc postgres-db-lb` or `kubectl get svc`.

In pgAdmin the hostname should-be `<node-ip>:<node-port>`.

We can also do `minikube service postgres-db-lb` to find the url.

## EDIT

Or more simply `minikube service <NAME_OF_SERVICE>`.